# How to download an HttpResponse into a file?

Tags: java, android, apache

My android app uses an API which sends a multipart HTTP request. I am successfully getting the response like so:

```
post.setEntity(multipartEntity.build());
HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
```

The response is the contents of an ebook file (usually an epub or mobi). I want to write this to a file with a specified path, lets says "/sdcard/test.epub".

File could be up to 20MB, so it'll need to use some sort of stream, but I can just can't wrap my head around it. Thanks!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

well it is a simple task, you need the `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` use permission.. then simply retrieve the `InputStream`

```
InputStream is = response.getEntity().getContent();
```

Create a FileOutputStream

```
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "test.epub"))
```

and read from is and write with fos

```
int read = 0;
byte[] buffer = new byte[32768];
while( (read = is.read(buffer)) > 0) {
  fos.write(buffer, 0, read);
}

fos.close();
is.close();
```

Edit, check for tyoo

Comment: Perfect. The fact that response.getEntity().getContent() gives an input stream was the missing piece of the puzzle. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> First is the method:

```
public HttpResponse setHTTPConnection() throws IOException, NullPointerException, URISyntaxException {
       HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
       HttpRequestBase requestMethod = new HttpGet();
       requestMethod.setURI(new URI("***FileToDownlod***"));
       BasicHttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();


       return client.execute(requestMethod, localContext);
   }
```

> Second is an actual code:

```
File downloadedFile = new File("filePathToSave");
       HttpResponse fileToDownload = setHTTPConnection();
       try {
           FileUtils.copyInputStreamToFile(fileToDownload.getEntity().getContent(), downloadedFile);
       } finally {
           fileToDownload.getEntity().getContent().close();
       }
```

> Please make sure to change "***filePathToSave***" to where to save the file and 
>   "***FileToDownlod***" to from where to download accordingly.
>
> "***filePathToSave***" is where you want to save the file, if you choose to save it locally then you can simply point to the desktop but don't forget to give a name to your file like "/Users/admin/Desktop/downloaded.pdf" (in Mac).
>
> "***FileToDownlod***" is in the form of URL e.g "https://www.doesntexist.com/sample.pdf"
>
> Don't panic as the second piece will ask to declare in throws clause or catch multiple exceptions. This piece of code was for a specific purpose please customize for your own need.

Answer (score 0):

As you said response is content of book or simple meaning that **you are getting response as file but not able to save response as file**.

Use this

```
HttpResponse<Path> response = client.send(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofFile(Paths.get("/sdcard/test.epub"));
```